# provide sleep interval at certain interval of time in Java

Tags: java, sleep, intervals

I have below code from my function where i am trying to take the parameters from database that is `MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPT` and based on this i will  be going to send an alert if the check gets failed. The current code will try to take the value from `MAX_FIELD_ATTEMPT` and check immediately after one another. Now i just want to put the `sleep` after every attempt for 5 minutes. So for example if the `MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPT` is 3 then for first attempt it will try to check immediately,again it will sleep for 5 minutes and try to check,in this way based on interval it will try to check the the number of times for `MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPT`.

```
private String connect(KpiDefinition kpiDef)
    {
        FtpSftpServer ftpSftpServer = kpiDef.getFtpSftpServer();

        // FTP key
        String serverName = ftpSftpServer.getServerName();

        // Retrieving ftp details from rator retail db
        Map<String, String> serverDetails = getServerDetailsFromRator(kpiDef,
                serverName);

        if (serverDetails == null || serverDetails.isEmpty())
        {
            errorMessage = "Error while retrieving FTP Details from Retail DB.";
            logger.debug(errorMessage);
        } else

            {
                boolean success = false;
                // We would attempt to connect till the max failed attempts
                // defined on the resource are reached. However if the
                // connection is already successful or if the connection has
                // failed due to Authentication Failure, then we will not try
                // again and simply come out of the loop.
                Long maxFailedAttempts = kpiDef.getFtpSftpServer()
                        .getMaxFailedAttempts();
                if (maxFailedAttempts == null || maxFailedAttempts == 0)
                {
                    maxFailedAttempts = 1l;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < maxFailedAttempts; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        success = connect(serverName, protocol, serverAddress,
                                serverPort, username, password);
                        if (!success)
                        {
                            String message = "Could not connect to " + protocol
                                    + " server " + serverName
                                    + " - Authorization failed.";
                            logger.debug(message);
                            errorMessage = message;
                            deactivateKPI(kpiDef, authenticateFailedMessage);
                            // do not attempt to try again if the KPI fails with
                            // authentication Exception.
                            break;
                        }
                        // Also come out of the loop if the connection was
                        // successful. We do not need to continue to attempt to
                        // connect.
                        break;                  
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5)` in the locations you deem appropriate

Edit:

I would try changing the success conditional in your for loop just a little bit

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxFailedAttempts; i++)
{
    try
    {
        success = connect(serverName, protocol, serverAddress, 
                                      serverPort, username, password);
        if (!success)
        {
            String message = "Could not connect to " + protocol
                                + " server " + serverName
                                + " - Authorization failed.";
            logger.debug(message);
            errorMessage = message;

            try
            {
                deactivateKPI(kpiDef, authenticateFailedMessage);
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ae)
            {
                // do not attempt to try again if the KPI fails with
                // authentication Exception.
                ae.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }

        // Also come out of the loop if the connection was
        // successful. We do not need to continue to attempt to
        // connect.
        break;                  
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me where actully i have to put this sleep because as i mentioned i have to provide sleep after interval of every 5 minutes until the max_attempt_failed field value has been checked

Comment: editted with some code. idk what the authentication exception is that you mention but presumably its getting thrown by `deactivateKPI()` so catch it and don't do the sleep unless its successful. Either way though, break out of the look after the try/catch